# String para HTML

Tags: javascript, meteorjs

Boa tarde, não sei bem se esse é o título mais apropriado mas é o seguinte...

Estou usando Meteor e mongodb.

Tenho 2 input, um onde eu digito o nome do site e outro que eu digito o site "www.exemplo.com.br", que então no javascript eu tenho o seguinte:

```
var siteCad = '<a href="http://'+ site +'">' + nome + '</a>';
```

Depois eu insiro o siteCad dentro de uma collection do mongoDB.
Gostaria de mostrar esses links todos cadastros dentro de uma <.li>, porém o que está acontecendo é que ele mostra o texto todo, desde o <.a href... até o "ponto e virgula", quero mostrar direto o link, como se estivesse direto do html.

Resumindo, tenho tags html com propriedades preenchidas no mongoDB no formato de string e gostaria de passar para html.

Alguém tem algum exemplo ou referência que eu possa dar uma olhada?

Comment: Em geral não é uma boa idéia gerar HTML usando concatenação de strings como você está fazendo. Você fica vulnerável a injeções de Javascript (XSS) se o usuário botar tags html no nome ou um "onhover" no campo do site.

Comment: E porque você quer inserir HTML no banco de dados? Não seria melhor inserir um registro com o nome e o site e gerar o html mais tarde?

Comment: é o que estou pensando agora, porém não sei como fazer para inserir o site no href lá no próprio html dai, estou iniciando os estudos em meteor na verdade. Como eu faria para setar uma variavel no href?

Comment: Se eu tento fazer assim: <a href={{site}}>, simplesmente não funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Use com 3 chaves:

```
{{{siteCad}}}
```

Link: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/README.md
3 brackets renderizam uma string html sem escapar.
 Lembrando que isso pode dar espaço a um ataque de XSS, então, use com cuidado.

Comment: Bom dia, valeu pela resposta... já havia feito assim, o problema é que não deu certo no inicio pois estava fazendo assim <a href="http://" + {{siteCad}}... mas depois que eu fiz assim como tu falou, deu certinho. Valeu!

Comment: De nada! Fico feliz em ajudar.